# Ubuntu home folder issue

Tags: ubuntu

I dual booted windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04. I followed a tutorial and mounted a 38GB partition at /home. Now that my /home folder is almost full (2MB remaining), but when I select "properties" in the drop down menu from home folder, it says it's totalling at 100 and so GB. I want to know why is that and if it's possible to extend my home folder as my root directory still has quite some space.

Comment: *"I followed a tutorial and mounted a 38GB partition at /home."*  This is exactly why all those people recommending standalone PC users create umpteen partitions when **you only need 1** (and only one is almost certainly better for most people) deserve to be put in stocks and left out in the sun for a few days with half a cup of water between them.

Comment: But you're not quite helping by that. No offense

Comment: You're right, all apologies.  That was for posterity.  There is a graphical paritioning tool, **[gparted](http://gparted.org/)**, that is available on Ubuntu and should help you do what you want.  Have a look at it, but when you actually do this you will probably have to run it from a live CD (it will already be installed there, they all use it), because it will want you to unmount the root partition, I think.

Comment: It's alright. Can I simply not use the /home folder to store my files and directly move them to the root directory?

Comment: @xXJJJasonMokXx - you could create a temporary directory, say `mkdir /myhome`, and put the files in there. You'll need to set the permissions on this dir. so that your username can have permissions to use it. `chown -R myuser /myhome`.

Comment: So I can just keep it like that? without moving it back to a extended home?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer -- as per my comment you should try `gparted` from a live CD if you want to resize/add/delete partitions.  There are already [many Q&A's here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gparted?sort=votes&pageSize=15), and if you have a specific issue with it that isn't dealt with there, you can ask about that.

But with regard to your other idea:

> Can I simply not use the /home folder to store my files and directly move them to the root directory?

Yes, you can do something like this.  Presumably, it is just a few particular folders in your home that hold most of this data, because the normal configuration, cache, etc. will not add up to 30+ GB.

First, you want to create a directory in the root partition.  Presuming `/opt` is part of that (you could also use `/media`, or just a new toplevel):

```
sudo mkdir /opt/userdata
sudo chmod 777 /opt/userdata
```

You should now as a normal user be able to create a subdirectory for yourself in there and move entire folders into it.  To keep whatever functionality you now have in relation to the location of those folders, create a symbolic link after you move them:

```
ln -s /opt/userdata/me/myBigStuff ~/myBigStuff
```

Here the first path is the existing directory that you moved, and the second path is the one you want linked to it.  See `man ln` for more details.

You could move your entire home directory this way, but doing it on a slightly finer scale will allow you to create some free space without wasting the whole partition by emptying it.

An easy way to move folders is:

```
mv ~/myBigStuff /opt/userdata/me
```

Presuming `/opt/userdata/me` *is a directory*, this will remove `myBigStuff` from `$HOME` and leave a `/opt/userdata/me/myBigStuff`.

Comment: Thank you first. I tried, and it says it requires 30 more GBs to be able to copy those files into /opt/userdata

Comment: What does the output of `df /opt/userdata` tell you?  If it is on the root partition, and the root partition is *also* full, then your problem is a little different than described.  If it isn't on the root partition, check `df /` to be sure, and just move the userdata directory to there (i.e. `/userdata`).

Comment: df /opt/userdata output: Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda4       98299524 18858056  74425100  21% /

Comment: According to that you should have 74.4 GB available on the partition.

Comment: Well I clicked properties on "computer" it does say 79 GB free

Comment: How are you trying to copy the files?

Comment: I ctrl C and ctrl V

Comment: Try, e.g., `mv /home/me/myBigStuff /opt/userdata/me` (where `me` is a directory) instead.  I'll edit that into the answer.

Comment: I am doing that command and seems like it's taking quite a long time after part of the folders popped up in the new directory, it doesn't seem to be doing anything. Is it normal?

Comment: I guess it depends on the size of the individual files.  If you think `mv` isn't working, you can kill it (ctrl-c) and while the last file being moved will not be complete in the *destination*, it will still be in the *source* intact (but completely moved files will be gone).  You can then try moving the individual files or subdirectories the same way.

Comment: It finally did the job but its not right. For example some applications seem to be not getting their data and the I just can't go to certain folders like the ones in "places"

Comment: Did you put all the correct symlinks in place with `ln`?  Your home directory should look exactly the same as it did before.

Comment: Sorry sir. I think I've missed that part. Gotta go to bed anyway. I'll do it tomorrow, thanks for the help bud

Comment: Now that I've done that symbolic link command, applications still need an initial setup or some sort. Any ideas

Comment: Do I have to like re-link the home folder to the new "home" folder? (i.e. /opt/userdata/me). Since I noticed that the applications aren't recognizing the new path to the "home" dir

Comment: You have to make sure the symlinks from `$HOME` to `/opt/userdata/me` leave `$HOME` looking exactly the same as it did originally.  This way, you don't have to (and **should not**) provide any new paths to applications.  They will treat the symlinked directories the same way they would normal ones.